# Java methods don't always need to declare throwing checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, unhandled-exception

I discovered today a pattern I thought for sure should be an "Unhandled exception type" compile error:

```
public void foo() {
    try {
        // do something fun
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw e; // only a compile error sometimes
    }
}
```

Notice how `foo` does not include `throws Throwable` in the method declaration, even though it may throw one.  If the code inside the `try/catch` does not throw any checked exceptions, then you don't need to declare the checked exception in the method signature

If we replace `// do something fun` with some actual checked-exception-throwing code, such as `"".getBytes("")`, the compiler recognizes that an exception must be thrown, and you can include `throws UnsupportedEncodingException` in the method declaration to fix the compile error (note that you still don't need to include `throws Throwable`, even though the catch block defines it as `Throwable e`

I've tried this as far back as Java 6, and it works there too.  **When did the Java compiler get this smart?  Are there any security checks in place to make sure this can't be easily exploited to do funny things?** Am I getting too excited about nothing?

(An example of a "funny thing": say `do something` was actually a call to an external library. At compile time, you use a version that does not throw any checked exceptions, but at runtime, you switch it for a version that *does* - now you have unchecked checked exceptions flowing throughout your code!)

Comment: By the way, exception checkedness is not a security feature.

Comment: @immibis - Thanks for the dup find - I spent a while looking but apparently couldn't figure out the right search terms. Looks like you had the same question!